# Unable to connect to Jupyter Notebook served by Docker

Tags: bash, docker, jupyter-notebook, docker-for-mac

I've been learning Docker with the end goal of using it to serve up and share Jupyter Notebooks. Below is an example Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERRED 1
RUN pip install jupyter

RUN useradd --create-home --home-dir /home/docker --shell /bin/bash docker
RUN adduser docker sudo

ADD start.sh /home/docker/start.sh
RUN chmod +x /home/docker/start.sh
RUN chown docker /home/docker/start.sh

ADD prod_sentiment.ipynb /home/docker/prod_sentiment.ipynb
ADD output.txt /home/docker/output.txt
RUN chmod +x /home/docker/output.txt
RUN chown docker /home/docker/output.txt

EXPOSE 8888
RUN usermod -a -G sudo docker
RUN echo "docker ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
USER docker

ENV HOME=/home/docker
ENV SHELL=/bin/bash
ENV USER=docker

RUN printenv
CMD ./home/docker/start.sh
```

The `start.sh` file looks as such:

```
#! /bin/sh
echo 'starting'
nohup jupyter notebook --no-browser > /home/docker/output.txt
```

I then:

```
docker build --rm -t 'test' .
docker run -d -ti -p 8888:8888 test
```

From this point, I would presume I should be able to navigate to `localhost:8888` and see the Jupyter Notebook. If I connect to the container via: `docker exec -i -t container_id /bin/bash` I can `tail -f /home/docker/output.txt` to see that I can curl it from within the Docker container. Likewise `ps auwx | grep 'jupyter'` confirms the Jupyter Notebook webserver is running.

Beyond binding the port as such `8888:8888` and `EXPOSING` it in the Dockerfile, what am I missing? Whenever I connect to `http://localhost:8888` it says 'localhost didn't send any data'.

I'm using Docker for Mac Version 1.12.1-beta26.1 build 1200.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your issue is that jupyter is only listening on the loopback interface by default. You can change this by running jupyter with the option `--ip=0.0.0.0` which will cause it to bind on all interfaces (inside the container).

EDIT: There is also some more information on this [in the jupyter documentation](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html#docker-cmd). Plus an example they provide in that documentation:

```
# Add Tini. Tini operates as a process subreaper for jupyter. This prevents
# kernel crashes.
ENV TINI_VERSION v0.6.0
ADD https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini /usr/bin/tini
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/tini
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/tini", "--"]

EXPOSE 8888
CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--port=8888", "--no-browser", "--ip=0.0.0.0"]
```